# How to export date column to excel in correct format via ExcelLibrary

Tags: excel, vb.net, datatable, excellibrary

I am exporting multiple DataTables to an Excel-file using ExcelLiabrary. The problem is that date column in all datatables, are being exported as number. DataTables are filled with data retrieved from Sql Server where the column type is date. Datagrids are also showing it correctly but in the excel it become numbers.

Here is the code to populate DataTable

```
Dim command = New SqlCommand("getdeta", sqlConn)
command.CommandType = 
CommandType.StoredProcedure
Dim adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(command)
dt1 = New DataTable()
adapter.Fill(dt1)
dgv1.DataSource = dt1
```

and here is to Export data to Excel

```
Dim fileName = ExportAllDialog.FileName
datasetForExport.Tables.Add(dt1)
datasetForExport.Tables.Add(dt2)
ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook(fileName, datasetForExport)
```

Comment: Well, internally a date in Excel is in fact a number. So this is only a formatting problem. I don't know ExcelLibrary, maybe there are functions to do the formatting right afterwards.

Comment: I know that and it can be formatted in the excel but as I mentioned there are multiple sheets/datasets so it is not good to put to burden of formatting on user.

Comment: Yes, thats right, but you can do that with VB.NET. I don't know if ExcelLibrary has this option. I do it with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. If you like I would post some code. But mixing up two approaches is maybe not a good idea.

Comment: I've used Interop.Excel previously. it is very slow or may be I was using it incorrectly. In ExcelLibrary, as you can see the code is very clean and it takes no time to create excel file regardless of the data size.

Comment: Is there any documentation of ExcelLiabrary?. I am unable to find it.

Comment: As I read in other posts there is really a lack of documentation for ExcelLibrary if we talk about [this one](https://code.google.com/archive/p/excellibrary/). In addition the last version is from 2011, thats quite old. Or are we talking about [this one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExpertXls.ExcelLibrary/)? There are many Excel Libraries out there. I dont think Excel Interop is slow, but maybe it depends on the size of your tables. I have some code which adds all cells in one action, so it should be also fast with bigger tables. And it has no problems with dates.

Comment: Please post your code and I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

So here is some code for the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel approach:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class ExcelBook
    Private EXL As Excel.Application
    Private Book As Excel.Workbook
    Private Sheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Private MyFileName As String

    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        ' Save and close the currently loaded Excel file
        Close(True)
        ' Delete the local reference to the app BEFORE destroy
        EXL = Nothing

        MyBase.Finalize()
    End Sub

    Private Sub OpenApplication()
        If EXL IsNot Nothing Then Return

        EXL = New Excel.Application
        EXL.Visible = False
        EXL.DisplayAlerts = False
    End Sub

    Public Sub Open(Filename As String)
        Open(Filename, 1)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Open(Filename As String, SheetIndex As Object)
        OpenApplication()

        ' If another Excel file is open, close it
        Close(True)

        If File.Exists(Filename) Then
            Book = EXL.Workbooks.Open(Filename)
        Else
            Book = EXL.Workbooks.Add()
        End If

        ' Turns off warning messages when saving older files
        Book.CheckCompatibility = False

        UseSheet(SheetIndex)

        MyFileName = Filename
    End Sub

    Public Sub Close(Save As Boolean)
        If Book Is Nothing Then Return

        If File.Exists(MyFileName) Then
            Book.Close(Save)
        Else
            If Save Then Book.SaveAs(MyFileName)
            Book.Close()
        End If

        Sheet = Nothing
        Book = Nothing

        MyFileName = Nothing
    End Sub

    Public Function UseSheet(Index As Object) As Boolean
        If Book Is Nothing Then Return False

        Try
            Sheet = DirectCast(Book.Sheets(Index), Excel.Worksheet)
            Sheet.Activate()
            Return True
        Catch Ex As COMException
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Sub AddSheet(NewName As String)
        AddSheet(NewName, Nothing)
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddSheet(NewName As String, Before As Object)
        If Book Is Nothing Then Return
        If SheetExists(NewName) Then Return

        If Before Is Nothing OrElse Not SheetExists(Before) Then
            Sheet = CType(Book.Sheets.Add(After:=Book.Sheets(Book.Sheets.Count)), Excel.Worksheet)
        Else
            Sheet = CType(Book.Sheets.Add(Before:=Book.Sheets(Before)), Excel.Worksheet)
        End If
        Sheet.Activate()
        Sheet.Name = NewName
    End Sub

    Function SheetExists(Index As Object) As Boolean
        If Book Is Nothing Then Return False

        Dim LocalSheet As Excel.Worksheet

        Try
            LocalSheet = DirectCast(Book.Sheets(Index), Excel.Worksheet)
        Catch Ex As COMException
            LocalSheet = Nothing
        End Try

        Return LocalSheet IsNot Nothing
    End Function

    Public Sub RenameSheet(NewName As String)
        If Sheet Is Nothing Then Return

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(NewName) Then Sheet.Name = NewName
    End Sub

    Public Sub FormatColumns(Columns As String, NewFormat As String)
        If Sheet Is Nothing Then Return

        Dim Rng = DirectCast(Sheet.Columns(Columns), Excel.Range)
        Rng.NumberFormat = NewFormat
    End Sub

    Public Sub ImportTable(Table As DataTable)
        If Sheet Is Nothing Then Return
        If Table Is Nothing Then Return
        If Table.Columns.Count = 0 Then Return

        Dim Matrix(Table.Rows.Count, Table.Columns.Count) As Object
        Dim Col As Integer

        ' Copy the datatable to an array
        For Row As Integer = 0 To Table.Rows.Count - 1
            For Col = 0 To Table.Columns.Count - 1
                Matrix(Row, Col) = Table.Rows(Row).Item(Col)
            Next
        Next

        ' Add the column headers starting in A1
        Col = 0
        For Each Column As DataColumn In Table.Columns
            Sheet.Cells(1, Col + 1) = Column.ColumnName
            Col += 1
        Next

        ' Add the data starting in cell A2
        If Table.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Sheet.Range(Sheet.Cells(2, 1), Sheet.Cells(Table.Rows.Count + 1, Table.Columns.Count)).Value = Matrix
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Then you could use this function to export your DataSet:

```
Private Sub ExportDataSet(DS As DataSet, Filename As String)
    Dim DT As DataTable
    Dim First As Boolean = True

    With New ExcelBook
        .Open(Filename)
        For Each DT In DS.Tables
            If First Then
                .RenameSheet(DT.TableName)
                First = False
            Else
                .AddSheet(DT.TableName)
            End If
            .ImportTable(DT)
        Next
        .UseSheet(1)
        .Close(True)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Aranxo: I am very thankful for your time and efforts but as you can see the interop code is too long and complicated compare to ExcelLiabrary. I would prefer to add some VBA code in excel to automate the process of formatting if nothing found here regarding ExcelLiabrary. Thank you again for your time and efforts.